# regex text matching

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I wrote some regexp. It works when I execute it with string typed in console, but not in some cases in my script.

Here is my console output:

```js
>body
["VERSION:2.1", "N:;S Wicius;;;", "FN:S Wicius", "TEL;PREF;CELL:000000000"]
>records.line
/^([^:;]+)(?:;([^:]+))?:(.+)$/gm
>records.line.exec( body[1] )
null
>body[1] == "N:;S Wicius;;;"
true
>records.line.exec( "N:;S Wicius;;;" )
["N:;S Wicius;;;", "N", undefined, ";S Wicius;;;"]

>for( var i = 0; i < body.length; i++ ) {
  var line = [];
  if( line = records.line.exec( body[i] ) )
    console.log( line )
}
["VERSION:2.1", "VERSION", undefined, "2.1"]
["FN:S Wicius", "FN", undefined, "S Wicius"]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Can you explain a little more clearly?

Comment: Is `body[1]` indeed that string, and is `body` not a sparse array?

Comment: typeof body[1] yields "string". I want to parse that for to parse all strings in "body" array.

Comment: `body` is text splitted by `\n`. Can this cause a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is caused by the combination of the following factors:

1. records.line is the same object in each iteration
2. regex is defined with /g modifier and
3. `exec` method changes [lastIndex](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/regexp_lastindex.htm) property of your regexp object

> lastIndex is a read/write property of RegExp objects. For regular
>   expressions with the "g" attribute set, it contains an integer that
>   specifies the character position immediately following the last match
>   found by the RegExp.exec( ) and RegExp.test( ) methods. These methods
>   use this property as the starting point for the next search they
>   conduct.
>
> This property allows you to call those methods repeatedly, to
>   loop through all matches in a string and works only if the "g"
>   modifier is set.

You can fix the issue by changing any of these 3 conditions (you also could manually reset `records.line.lastIndex = 0` in each iteration). Your /g modifier seems to be useless, so just get rid of it.

Comment: That's it! /g modifier should not be there!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `body[1]` is not actually a string, but rather, is an object whose "ToPrimitive" operation yields `"N:;S Wicius;;;"`. So although `body[1] == "N:;S Wicius;;;"` is `true` (as you saw), `body[1] === "N:;S Wicius;;;"` will be `false`.

If you want to perform your regex-match on the string-value of `body[1]`, you can do this:

```
records.line.exec( '' + body[1] )
```

Comment: `body[1] === "N:;S Wicius;;;"` is true.
`records.line.exec( '' + body[1] )` works, but it is workaround. :<

Comment: I was wrong. `records.line.exec( '' + body[1] )` works, but only in console.